# In supervised learning, a general form for response $Y$ is $f(x) + \epsilon$, I want to be able to explain this and why we add a $\hat{}$ in $f(x)$

Tags: machine-learning, error, supervised-learning, estimators

People simply explain it like "If you estimated it, you should've put a hat on it!"

I am trying to introduce Machine Learning to people in a YouTube channel. I want to be able to CLEARLY help them understand why he have a $\hat{}$ in $\hat{f}(x)$.

So here's my reasoning. I want to make sure I have this PERFECTLY right.

In supervised learning, we are given the general form, $Y = f(x) + \epsilon$.

The truth is, if we were somehow, mysteriously able to obtain ALL data on the entire planet, $Y = f(x) + \epsilon$ would be the representation of the relationship between $Y$ and the set of variables $x$ (Assume $x$ is a vector of variables that we are measuring).

Now, it is also impossible to measure ALL possible variables! If we are trying to predict something like maybe a heart attack, we may not measure some variables like how your heart is pumping! And what's going on in your blood vessels. So there will ALWAYS be some irreducible error $\epsilon$ either because we don't have enough data to understand the pattern or some of the right variables which play an important role!

The reason for why he have a $\hat{}$ in $\hat{f}(x)$ is that we want to try our hardest to get as close to the population $f(x)$ as possible! The form $Y = f(x) + \epsilon$ DOES EXIST, but it is UNKNOWN and THIS PERFECT FORM CAN NEVER BE FOUND OUT since we can't possibly get someone to record the measurements of $x$ for all the people in the entire planet!

So we have some data called a (sample), we assume that the sample may be a representative of the population! An example of a sample maybe the 150 observations of the iris dataset having measurements of 4 variables and the type of iris as the response variable. Using our small number of observations whose response we know and believe that it came from $f(x)$ without the $\hat{}$, we try to a good estimate of $f(x)$, that's why we have a $\hat{}$ in $\hat{f}(x)$ to differentiate between the given responses in the sample (which is actually the representative of the population), and our predicted response using the $f(x)$ WE ESTIMATED OR CAME UP WITH.

My question is: Is my reasoning sound and correct?

Comment: The error term $\epsilon$ is not always additive. A more general form of the equation would be $Y = f(x, \epsilon)$. Moreover there are certainly many common data models, such as logistic regression, that are not typically understood as involving an explicit error term $\epsilon$

Comment: Alright. I've noted this down. What about the $\hat{}$ explanation? Is that correct?

Comment: What you describe is not a general description of surprised learning. The heart attack example is one where the type of expression with an additive error is really not what one would assume.

Comment: The $\hat f$ is correct!.